# Object#define_singelton_method in Ruby 2.1.0 defines private methods?

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax, ruby-2.1

```
object = Object.new
object.define_singleton_method(:foo) do
  :bar
end
object.foo
```

fails with `` private method `foo' called for #<Object:0x00000001e89580> (NoMethodError) ``. Ruby 2.0.0 does not behave like that. Is this a bug in 2.1.0 or intentional change?

Comment: Ask in ruby's bug tracker?

Comment: @Denis - good idea, 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. The bug was reported at [#9005](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9005) and [#9141](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9141#change-43088).

Answer (score 1):

Since `define_singleton_method` (and the other `define_method` methods) now return a symbol of the method name, you can fix this by adding `public` in front of any call to `define_method`.

`public define_method(:foo) { :bar }`